# Setting up a basic api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I'm trying to create a basic rails app. I created an apis controller like so

```
class ApisController < ApplicationController
    def calendar
       #code
       render json: @response
    end
end
```

and my routing file looks like this

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    get 'calendar' => 'apis#calendar'
end
```

Unfortunately i get the error `uninitialized constant Api`. I would ideally like to keep the api as simple as possible. Where am I going wrong

Any help is appreciated and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured using scopes instead of namespaces

```
scope :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    get 'calendar' => 'apis#calendar'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend wrapping it in a module. You can manage versioning the same way.

Here's an example:

https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2014/2/19/building-and-documenting-api-in-rails/